# parent, &, intercalation in css attribute

Tags: sass

I have the following code:

```
  &__menu {
    float: left;
    list-style: none none;
    padding: $navbar-menu_padding;
    [class^=#{&}__item] { 
    ....
}
```

I'm trying to an interpolation of `& - [class^=#{&}__item]`.

This will fail, with or without interpolation.

There is another option, besides writing the full name of the class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store parent class name into variable.

Scss:

```
.block {
  $this: &; // Variable

  &__item {
    color: red;
  }

  &:hover {
    // Using variable instead of full class name
    #{$this}__item {
      color: green;
    } 
  }
}
```

Css output:

```
.block__item {
  color: red;
}

.block:hover .block__item {
  color: green;
}
```